# how to get Azure AD b2c sign-in logs through Microsoft Graph programatically

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-graph-sdks

I need to get Azure AD B2C sing-in logs through Microsoft Graph API, I tried the following code it doesn't return any logs.

```
      var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns" };

        // Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
        // single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
        var tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"];
        // Values from app registration
        var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"];
        var clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"];
        var tenantName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantdomain"];

        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
        };

        // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

  var signIns =  graphClient.AuditLogs.SignIns.Request().GetAsync();
```

I get the following result but I don't get any data or sing-in logs

[image]

2- And if i change the method to the following:

```
 var signIns = graphClient.AuditLogs.SignIns.Request().GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I get the following error:

```
 ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID URI).
```

Comment: if it still failed to get the response, pls kindly share the latest error messages with me.

Comment: Any update on this question sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls using `var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };` instead. It's necessary.

And you may try to use `var signIns = await graphClient.AuditLogs.SignIns.Request().GetAsync();` since it's a sample code from [ms graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request).

If it still failed for you, pls go to Azure portal and your azure ad application to check if you had set the correct [api permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions). You must add **Application** permission `AuditLog.Read.All and Directory.Read.All` but not the delegated permission .

[image]